# Portably generate XML document without using a DOM

Tags: c++, xml

I have a need to generate XML documents from C++. For reasons of performance I don't want to use an XML parser such as Xerces, or TinyXML and generate a DOM which I then serialize, ideally I want a kind of "reverse SAX" interface. I also need the code to be really portable, across Windows, UNIX, MacOSX etc.

The only reference so far I've found is to [genx](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/genx/docs/Guide.html). Anyone got any other suggestions?

EDIT:
This question [what's the easiest way to generate xml in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303371/whats-the-easiest-way-to-generate-xml-in-c) actually seems to answer mine, or at least provides some links to other XML generating libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like libxml2 has a streaming API. See answer to question [create and stream large XML document in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311/create-and-stream-large-xml-document-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

[Rapidxml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) is very fast and pretty lightweight.

Comment: I'll look at that one as it does claim to be lightweight, so maybe constructing the DOM and then serialising it may not be too much of a memory overhead, but ideally I'd like a streaming interface.

Comment: I did explicitly say "not using a DOM".